# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. > Compilation error. See log for more details

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build, gradle-kotlin-dsl

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

build:gradle(Module:app)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

   

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uxx.xx.xxe"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 17
        versionName "0.1.14"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/assets/fonts']
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.SF'
        exclude 'META-INF/ECLIPSE_.RSA'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${rootProject.supportLibraryVersion}"
       compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${rootProject.googlePlayServicesVersion}"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.9'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.9'
    compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.1.9'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
```

build:gradle(Project)

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        //visualize the method count
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.6.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

ext.googlePlayServicesVersion = '10.2.0'
ext.supportLibraryVersion = '25.3.1'

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Solution Tried:**

1. Invalidate Caches/Restart
2. Build -> Clean Project
3. Update kotlin plugin, used lastest version of kotlin, google APIs.

**EDIT**

```
./gradlew build --stacktrace > logs.txt 2>logErrors.txt
```

logErrors.txt

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:8)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.processCompilerExitCode(Tasks.kt:286)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:260)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:160)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:141)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 70 more
```

Comment: Can you also post whatever is in the log?

Comment: hey, sorry. Actually I don't know where I should look for log. Can you help me that also @zsmb13

Comment: @zsmb13 I have look up in under message section but there is no log available

Comment: @zsmb13 I have added the log

Comment: You should probably [file an issue](http://kotl.in/issue) in the Kotlin bugtracker.

Comment: @Ankur_009, I have same issue. Did you find solution?

Comment: did you tried the option that I have mentioned in the question? @SattarHummatli

Comment: Yes, i've tried. The same result. @Ankur_009

Comment: I don't know specifically what was the reason but I had created the new project.  But I think it occurs when copy another project activity class to the new project. Try to restart the system (lame answer. as I don't know the exact solution)   @SattarHummatli

Comment: I ran into this problem today. Doing a Gradle clean then restarting Android Studio seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: Sometimes may help to update gradle version in `gradle-wrapper.properties` file

Comment: When I ran the build again, it worked, per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47292341/897007

Answer (score 247):

I got such error after a simple try of code refactoring. It has happened nor after some library was connected neither any changes in gradle. It looked like something in my code was wrong but the compiler could not find the issue. That's why I double checked all changes that I did and found that *I had somehow changed method signature in the interface but had not changed it in class that implements it*.
I got this error twice during one day and decided to share my experience. I hope that it is a temporary compiler bug.

**Solution 1** Possible solution is to go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Compiler -> and add "--stacktrace --debug" to Command-line Options. Read log and try to found the answer of what went wrong.

In new Android Studio 3.1.+, you can enable/disable console log details by pressing "Toggle View" on "Build" tab. There you can find the details. *Pay attention* that both modes can be useful for investigation of the problem's reason. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49717363/

[image]

**Solution 2** Click on `Gradle` (on the right side bar) then under `:app` choose `assembleDebug` (or `assembleYourFlavor` if you use flavors). Error will show up in **Run** tab. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51022296

**Solution 3** As a last resort. In the android studio, try Code -> Inspect Code -> Whole project > Done. Wait until the inspection is over and then correct errors in "General" section and possible ones in other sections.

**Note** The kapt3 can be a source of such bugs. I removed `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` and added `kapt { generateStubs = true }` into `android {}` section of build.gradle. It seems that the previous version of the kapt generator is bugs free. *(**Update.** It looks like a bug with kapt is gone on kotlin version 1.2.+)*

Comment: @newbie I hope one day we will get updates with fixes for such issues.

Comment: I have try moving to backward, I back  to use `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`, and my android studio back get error. but I try debug with terminal like this `./gradlew build` I have no error, and compile is successful. hmmm it's very weird.

Comment: I mean why `android studio` and `terminal` making different of result? and what code `android studio` to compile gradle?

Comment: @newbie it's difficult to find out why this happens. I have an explanation for all cases: android always contain a piece of magic =)

Comment: Well this solution in last Update somewhat works for me. remove the kotlin-kapt and add in kapt{generetaStubs = true}

Comment: The original (old) kapt is deprecated and will be removed completely soon after Kotlin 1.2. If you experience any problems with `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`, please file an issue to http://kotl.in/issue.

Comment: @yanex After the original kapt will be removed we will see how the new one will work. Maybe problem will gone at all with this update.

Comment: @yanex It looks like truth. With kotlin v1.2+ and new kapt I have not faced such issue for a long time.

Comment: Tried Solution 1. Nothing came in log and still issue persists.

Comment: @MalwinderSingh Check the updated answer. AS 3.1 can be the reason why you do not see log details.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky In android studio try Analyze -> Inspect Code -> Whole project. Wait until inspection is over and then correct errors in "General" section.

Comment: I am using Android studio 3.3 and kotlin version 1.3.20
Solution 3 helped me.  
Thanks so much.

Comment: Weird...simply adding the compiler flags "fixed" the problem for me...

Answer (score 118):

I had misleading error messages similar to the ones posted in the question:

> Compilation error. See log for more details

And:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:16)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.processCompilerExitCode(Tasks.kt:429)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:390)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:274)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:233)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
```

## Solution:

I solved it by

1. Clicking on `Gradle` (on the right side bar) ->
2. Then under `:app`
3. Then choose `assembleDebug` (or `assembleYourFlavor` if you use flavors)

In Picture:

1 & 2:

[image: s1]

3:

[image: s2]

Error will show up in **Run:** tab.

Comment: Thank you. Found the issue using this. One thing to note, is that the original gradle error that doesn't help much shows up first when scrolling back through the logs, keep scrolling back and you will find the original error. Easily identifiable by the blue link to the source file causing the issue.

Comment: I don't see "assembleDebug" if list

Comment: "./gradlew assembleDebug" at the project root will do the job

Comment: @user7856586 me too, did't find assembleDebug

Comment: @VikasPandey I forgot how I solve this problem. Maybe it's depends on AS version

Comment: ":app/Tasks/other/assembleDebug" is the current path

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 106):

If you are using AS 3.1 the new build graphical console isn't very helpful for finding out the source of the problem.

you need to click on toggle view and see the logs in text format to see the error and if needed to `Run with --stacktrace`

[image]

Comment: Thanks!! I had to do this after a couple of hours of debugging.. one thing I want to add to your answer is that the error might be some lines above the one that contains the "Compilation error. See log for more details" message.

Comment: thanks! it's more explicit to see the text errors. after hours of debugging, I found the right error. For me it was because of the @inject of the viewModel, I forgot to put the annotation on the viewModel constructor also

Comment: Funny enough, this is the only way to catch Dagger-related error. Ridiculous!

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I found that I forgot to import Log inside LoggingInterceptor.

Comment: An IDE as failed as an IDE if it's unable to convey compilation errors to the developer. Seriously Google: Work weekends until this is fixed.

Comment: thank you! thank you! thank you! @humazed this led me to the right path :)

Comment: @Nilzor I second that, and please change the tool windows back to the bottom. It is really annoying to have to do a treasure hunt for logcat.

Comment: @Nilzor It's not Google responsibility area. It's Jetbrains bug.

Comment: Thank you! Console view helped me, in graphical view I had 2 warnings, whether in console view I have 2 warning + 1 error, which was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 38):

This error shows up when there is Kotlin Compilation Error.

Run the below command to find where there is Kotlin Compilation Error,

```
gradlew clean assembleDebug (for Windows)
./gradlew clean assembleDebug (for Linux and Mac)
```

It will show you the exact location on which line there is Kotlin Compilation Error.

Comment: this one helped! thanks

Comment: Yep, this told me the exact error!

Comment: It worked for me, thanks a lot!!
THe problem was something with versions

Comment: Best solution for multi-module app.

Answer (score 18):

On Mac :

> go to Android Studio > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle-Android Compiler

On Windows :

> go to File > Settings > > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler

Now, in the Command-line Options field , add following three flags :

```
--stacktrace --info --scan
```

like shown below

[image]

Now , open the Build window from the bottom of Android studio
[image]

Then, there is a button on the left side of the Build window:

[image]

press this button , you will see detailed logs with exact code that is preventing the project from compiling

Answer (score 17):

**1 - Check if kotlin version is same across project**

Declare this in your project level gradle file

```
buildscript {
ext {
    kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
}
```

And make sure kotlin gradle plugin has the same version

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

**2 - Run build with parameters like `--stacktrace` `--debug` `--info` `--scan` one by one**

Read the error carefully and check if it mentions any of your files

**3 - Export logs from build and read them**

Run this command

```
./gradlew build --stacktrace > logs.txt 2>logErrors.txt
```

**4 - Inspect Code And Fix Any Problems You May Find**

Go to `Analyze -> Inspect Code` in Android Studio

**5 - Invalidate Caches , Clean & Rebuild Project**

If this does not fix your problem , you might have a dependencies issue , check them carefully , make your 1 is satisfied with all dependencies

Comment: my case ,i ve just update to  : ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'

Comment: in my case, running `./gradlew build --scan` revealed the error:
`e: This version (1.1.1) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.7.10 which is not known to be compatible.`

Answer (score 14):

In such case look at `gradle console` it will show the issue in detail with exact location which led to this compilation error.

In my case I was using `Butterknife` in one of my class and I had `auto-converted` that class to `kotlin` using android studio's utility

`Log in Gradle Console`

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedFolders(FileCollection)
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/Downloads/myproject/app/google-services.json
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources
:app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin
Using kotlin incremental compilation
:app:kaptDebugKotlin
e: /Users/Downloads/myproject/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/myproject/util/ConfirmationDialog.java:10: error: @BindView fields must not be private or static. (com.myproject.util.ConfirmationDialog.imgConfirmationLogo)
e: 

e:     private android.widget.ImageView imgConfirmationLogo;
e:                                      ^
e: /Users/Downloads/myproject/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/myproject/util/ConfirmationDialog.java:13: error: @BindView fields must not be private or static. (com.myproject.util.ConfirmationDialog.txtConfirmationDialogTitle)
e: 

e:     private android.widget.TextView txtConfirmationDialogTitle;
e:                                     ^
e: /Users/Downloads/myproject/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/myproject/util/ConfirmationDialog.java:16: error: @BindView fields must not be private or static. (com.myproject.util.ConfirmationDialog.txtConfirmationDialogMessage)
e: 

e:     private android.widget.TextView txtConfirmationDialogMessage;
e:                                     ^
e: /Users/Downloads/myproject/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/myproject/util/ConfirmationDialog.java:19: error: @BindView fields must not be private or static. (com.myproject.util.ConfirmationDialog.txtViewPositive)
e: 

e:     private android.widget.TextView txtViewPositive;
e:                                     ^
e: /Users/Downloads/myproject/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/myproject/util/ConfirmationDialog.java:22: error: @BindView fields must not be private or static. (com.pokkt.myproject.ConfirmationDialog.txtViewNegative)
e: 

e:     private android.widget.TextView txtViewNegative;
e:                                     ^
e: /Users/Downloads/myproject/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/myproject/util/ExitDialog.java:10: error: @BindView fields must not be private or static. (com.myproject.util.ExitDialog.txtViewPositive)
e: 

e:     private android.widget.TextView txtViewPositive;
e:                                     ^
e: /Users/Downloads/myproject/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/myproject/util/ExitDialog.java:13: error: @BindView fields must not be private or static. (com.myproject.util.ExitDialog.txtViewNegative)
e: 

e:     private android.widget.TextView txtViewNegative;
e:                                     ^
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:144)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:167)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:55)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:397)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$execCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:798)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2$$special$$inlined$withValidClientOrSessionProxy$lambda$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:825)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:797)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1004)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:865)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:791)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.access$doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:364)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1004)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.ifAlive$default(CompileServiceImpl.kt:865)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:336)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:205)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:89)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:76)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:365)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:354)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:139)
    ... 40 more


 FAILED
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Internal compiler error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 32s

16 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 9 up-to-date
```

As in my log it clearly shows issues are with declaration of variables with butterknife. So I looked into this issue and was able to solve it.

Comment: In my opinion it's better to use kotlin extensions instead of butterknife. But nevertheless thanks for sharing your experience. It can be helpfull for many people.

Comment: @Yazon2006 **kotlin** supports many of the android frameworks now thats why I gave it a try look at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-frameworks.html

Comment: You are right! But if we talking exactly about view initialization by @BindView in butterknife I discovered that kotlin extensions provide much more easy way to get views instances in code. Just take a look, you'll love it) https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Comment: @Yazon2006 Thanks for the link it's a lot easier than `butterknife`.

Answer (score 9):

I changed my project to use Androidx, so I used the migration tool but some files(many files), didn't change automatically. I opened each file (activities, enums, fragments) and I found so many errors. I corrected them but the compile still show me incomprehensible errors. After looking for a solution I found this answer that someone said:

go to Analyze >> Inspect code

[image]

Whole Project:

[image]

It took some time and then showed me the result below:

[image]

As I corrected the errors I thought were important, I was running the build until the remaining errors were no longer affecting the build.

My Android Studio details

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem.
The problem was that I incorrectly wrote the properties of the model in the attributes of the view:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{ferm.coin.value}"/>
```

This part was wrong:

```
@{ferm.coin.value}
```

When I wrote the correct property, the error was resolved.

Answer (score 6):

Please upgrade your kotlin version in your Gradle file to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
```

Answer (score 6):

For me, updating the kotlin version to the latest in app level build.gradle file and then syncing the project worked.
So the gradle file looks like the following (at the time of writing the answer):

```
buildscript{
    ...
    ...
    dependency{
        classpath "com.android.tools..."
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the answer. In my experience, falling back to version 1.5.10 from 1.6.0 solve the problem

Answer (score 5):

I was suffering the same problem I solved it by checking build tab and switch to **text mode**. Check the console it will show the problems 
mine was removing a drawable without deleting the usage and deleting a class without deleting the usage also
[Text mode button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECaWl.png)

Answer (score 4):

in my case I accidentally changed  `version="1.0"` to `xml version="1.0"` in my XML file.

I only had to change it back.

if you have the same problem and the solutions above didn't work for you.
open `Gradle Console` and scroll to `Run with --debug option` click it and it will show you more useful info about your error.

some notes:

this error doesn't appear directly after I make the change in XML it appear only after I change some java code. I think it has something to do with the instant run and build cash.

Answer (score 4):

This line work for me on mac or Linux.

```
./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found one solution to this problem.

Please follow below these steps:

1. Go to File->Settings->Compiler->add To --stacktrace --debug in Command-line-Options box and then apply & ok.
2. Rebuild a project.
3. Run a project.

Answer (score 3):

I want to add my solution to above, maybe it helps someone. When i create a `field` on a model via `Room` and do not generate `getter/setter` for the `field`. As a result project is not compiling and no clear errors.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the similar problem in no reason, i think it was caused by IDE(android studio). I have tried all of above solutions but not worked. Finally, in my own situation, i solved this problem by the following actions:
- Close the current project and remove it from the list of projects in android studio ,and reopen it by `Open an existing Android Studio project`, then it may be worked. I hope that my experience will be useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

I Had the same issue and finally discovered the reason. In my case it was a badly written Java method:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("register-user/")
Call<RegisterUserApiResponse> registerUser(
        @Field("email") String email,
        @Field("password") String password,            
        @Field("date") String birthDate,
);
```

Note the illegal comma after the "date" field. For some reason the compiler could not reveal this exact error, and came with the `':app:compileDebugKotlin'. > Compilation error` thing.

Answer (score 2):

upgraded Android Studio from 3.2.1 to 3.3 and the problem disappeared

Answer (score 2):

in my case:: I was using `kotlin extensions` to access and bind my views, I had recently moved a `view` to another screen and forgot to remove its reference from the previous fragment that caused this error.

`kotlin synthetic extensions` are not compile time safe. I really loved this but apparently in big projects, if this happens again I'm surely going to get a heart attack.

Answer (score 2):

run `gradle assembleDebug --scan` in Android studio Terminal, in my case I removed an element in XML and forgotten to remove it from code, but the compiler couldn't compile and show `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. > Compilation error. See log for more details` to me.

[image]

Comment: since I don't have gradle on my path in windows, I was able to use the gradle wrapper instead: gradlew assembleDebug --scan. This helped me see the error output that wasn't showing in my build log. Took about 5 minutes to run

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, and it was related to Kotlin and java files with the same name.

The issue appeared after I converted a java file to kotlin in one branch, and then merged my branches, but both files remained in the project.

The error didn't show the duplicated file name, but after adding

`kapt.incremental.apt=false`
to "gradle.properties" as suggested by this article:

Comment: Great, but please use the `Code Sample` format button (`{}`) for code pasting for better readability. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are experiencing this error, it is because your *build.gradle* file is missing the *kotlin plugin*, most answers recommend changing the kotlin version but in some cases, you don't even see the plugin under dependencies, maybe it's a react native thing since I experienced it with react native.

Go to *your_project* -> *android* -> *build.gradle* file and inject the kotlin dependency with the code below under dependencies

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21"
```

replace the `1.7.21` at the end with the latest version of kotlin.

Your ***buildscript*** should look like the code below

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 30
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2")
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.21" // change 1.7.21 to the latest kotlin version
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I had a same problem. To solve this problem just open your all files(recent working files) in Which you made the changes and check did you forget to delete some which should be deleted.

**In my case the problem was with the Unreferenced code which I was using in one of my file and that code is present in that file which should not be present in that file because I was using an interface which I have deleted from my project but I forget to deleted from one of my file).**

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I attempted to upgrade `play_services`and `firebase` versions to `15.0`. Going back to `11.4.2` fixed my issue...

Answer (score 1):

My scenario:

old Kotlin dataclass:

```
data class AddHotelParams(val destination: Place?, val checkInDate: LocalDate,
                      val checkOutDate: LocalDate?): JsonObject
```

new Kotlin dataclass:

```
data class AddHotelParams(val destination: Place?, val checkInDate: LocalDate,
                      val checkOutDate: LocalDate?, val roundTrip: Boolean): JsonObject
```

The problem was that I forgot to change the object initialization in some parts of the code. I got a generic "compileInternalDebugKotlin" error instead of being told where I needed to change the initialization.

changing initialization to all parts of the code resolved the error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I forgot to add the return type to a function in my inherited class from RoomDatabase:

```
abstract class LocalDb : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun progressDao(): ProgressDao
}
```

The **ProgressDao** return type was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Gradle > your_project > app > Tasks > Build > assembleAndroidTest
Run it and see what is the problem

[image]

In my case it was:
[image]

Upgrading version fix the problem:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with **3 errors** (**flamingo** version)

```
- Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
- A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWo
rkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
- Compilation error. See log for more details
```

I've tried clean project, **rebuild** and **validate cache** and still. I used **inspect** tool to get all the *warnings* but i confused from the number of warnings.

my **solution** was to `comment` every file in `kotlin` and `resources` and let only `MainActivity` then **run** the code and that worked very very well then began to uncomment file after another till I found the **problem** was in `navigation file` include an **argument** with a **different package** name (when I moved the `data class` to another `package` it didn't change in navigation file so caused the **error**)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible recent solution is changing gradle version to:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-rc2'
```

and updating build tool

Answer (score 0):

In my case error was caused by this line

> @BindColor(R.color.colorAccent)
>     var mColor: Int? = 0

Solved By

> @JvmField
>       @BindColor(android.R.color.white)
>       @ColorInt
>       internal var mColor: Int = 0

Error in GradleConsole

:app:kaptDebugKotlin
e: \app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\MainFragment.java:23: error: @BindColor field type must be 'int' or 'ColorStateList'. (com.sample.MainFragment.mColor)
e:

e:     private java.lang.Integer mColor;

Answer (score 0):

i was surprised to find that when i had a class that was closed it produced this vague error. changing it to a open class resolved the issue.

```
before:

 class DefaultSubscriber<T> : Observer<T> {//...
}

after:

open class DefaultSubscriber<T> : Observer<T> {//...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below changes worked for me

I change distribution URL, located in gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip
```

And

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
```

kotlin version 1.2.71

Answer (score 0):

If you have Hilt in your app. Make sure you have **annotated** your module class with

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm migrating an old personal project and this message appeared. I was using AS 4.2 stable and removing the `compose` buildFeature solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this issue when you are trying to run the app for the first time on a Physical Device:
Check you have enabled USB debugging in mobile settings(visible in Developer options). and also install via USB option. Later allow the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding additional code to the mainactivity of my Flutter project caused me to have a similar problem. kt file by accident, thus I believe you might have made a mistake in mainactivity. kt so compiler throws this instead of compiling the code:
exception in app:compileDebugKotlin

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same error after upgrading to Android Studio Giraffe Canary 3.
I am using JetpackCompose.

What worked for me is changing the kotlin version from `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false` to `id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false` within the build.gradle project file

````
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
    }



}
plugins {
    ...
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.10' apply false
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred when I migrated my Java files to kotlin. Few things to look for:

In your build.gradle file (app level) make sure you have kotlin plugin support

```
plugins {
   ...
   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
   ...
   kotlinOptions {
      jvmTarget = '1.8'
   }
}
```

In you build.gradle file (Top Level) make sure you have this

```
plugins {
   ...
   id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
}
```

If not working, [Check out this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45016580/4370398)

Answer (score 0):

Only and Only switch from java 8 to java 11

Answer (score 0):

[image]

after that
[image]

```
./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue while attempting to merge two branches. The following steps resolved the issue for me:

1. Build -> Clean Project
2. Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score -6):

In my case, this worked:

```
flutter create .
```

Comment: the question is about a Kotlin Android Project not Flutter.

Comment: Flutter can use Kotlin for Android dev.