# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm new to using Kotlin and trying to set it up with Dagger2, I've seen some few examples but none of them seem to work for me.

I keep getting this

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>
> > Internal compiler error. See log for more details

I have my build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.exampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    kapt {
        generateStubs = true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVer = '25.0.0'
    daggerVer = '2.8'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Support lib
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVer}"

    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVer}"
    compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVer}"
    provided "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:${javaxVer}"

    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"


}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Switch to the gradle console and look at the log output. The IDE only shows you that there was an error compiling, but you have to look at the output to see the error.

Comment: convert all related classes to kotlin

Answer (score 92):

Run your application with `./gradlew clean build` command to see what's exactly wrong with your code. Just paste it into the Terminal in Android Studio.

Comment: i tried. it starts downloading the same gradle version zip which is already installed and activated.

Comment: for windows user, use backslash. Something like .\gradlew clean build

Comment: use `chmod +x ./gradlew` before if it's your first time calling *gradlew* in linux.

Comment: Amazing. This really helped to see what errors needs to be fixed. Thanks!

Comment: It appears that for every new project, I have these massive build errors and each time is for a different (some times dumb) reason.  This technique, using the command line parameter, allowed me to see my error using Float in the annotations for my Dao / Database (using Room).

 ./gradlew clean build --debug --stacktrace

Comment: In my case backslash `.\gradlew clean build` OR `gradlew clean build` is working.

Comment: Wow. This really helped me to find the issue.

Comment: All i got was "BUILD FAILED in 40m 30s"

Answer (score 27):

If you are using the Room database and getting a KAPT error, just check your

1. Database declarations
2. Data Access Object declarations
3. Data class fields

**It's a problem arising due to improper usage of annotations of Room.
For more information use your build logs**.

[image: You can see here in this picture before expanding the error log, I can see the annotation missing error.]

Comment: If some error  occur in the  SQL statement  of  the Dao , also get the error

Answer (score 27):

In my case I replaced this

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.27'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.27'
```

by

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.27'
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.27"
```

and solved the problem

Comment: This worked for me too. Can anyone give insight on why? I thought the kapt plugin provided all the annotations Dagger needed.

Answer (score 18):

I faced this problem for a while. What helped me a lot was reading the build tab because it gave the reasons the library was failing.
Here is the tab [image: Build tab]
I had many problems,
1. I haven't added the new entity I created into the @Database annotation
2. I haven't added the @Dao annotation in my interface
3. I haven't updated some variables names that was wrote in a @Query annotation
So I had to kill problem by problem, finally it could run later.
In Addition, I was cleaning my project and rebuilding to ensure code doesn't get stuck. Also close and open Android Studio.

Futhermore, you can check this answer to help you find the error [enable more log on error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45016580/8650422)

Answer (score 10):

I faced this problem for a while. My mistake was using private access specifier with @Inject field.

If you are using Dagger then check for @Inject private fields or to know the exact cause add this as Command-line options:

```
--stacktrace --info --scan
```

On Mac, go to *Android Studio > Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler*

On Windows, go to *File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler*

Comment: for me the problem was not the dagger, but upvoted for command line options

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I forgot to add the room db entities to the database

```
@Database(version = 1,
    entities = [DummyEntity::class]
 )
```

Answer (score 6):

Issue can be connected with Room and Kotlin 1.4.10.

Try to change `android.arch.persistence` to `androidx.room` for Room dependencies:

Use

`kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"`

instead of

`kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$roomVersion"`

Comment: I worked with persistence room before , when I added hilt dependency it caused unknown error, it took 2 days me until I found your comment, Thanks,

Comment: It's work!
after a lot of search, your solution fixed my problem, Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 6):

If You are using Hilt and Field Injection Then Remove Private From Field Injected Object this worked For me

```
@Inject
private lateinit var helper: Helper
```

to

```
@Inject
lateinit var helper: Helper
```

Comment: omg this was it, I can't believe it, thank you

Answer (score 6):

Just Replace kept Keyword to annotationProcessor and everything works fine.

Answer (score 5):

I faced similar problem when setting up dagger2. It was finally resolved when I changed this line:

```
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVer}"
```

to this

```
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVer}"
```

Comment: More than 2 years later, upgrading to the latest to start using Compose in an old project, this saved my day. It was just that word replacement :|

Comment: @Austin Chang Well played :>

Answer (score 3):

**Worked for me:**

I also had the same problem and solved it by adding this to gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.java.home=<go to project structure, copy JDK location and past here>
```

This ensures that gradlew uses the same JDK as Android Studio

Comment: That one fixed my problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It fixed my problem. Kudos !! :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is probably related to the use of Room. I used the command Łukasz Kobyliński suggested in his comment

> `./gradlew clean build`

and in my case I had to add a converter for Date type.

You can find the converter in the official docs: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data#type-converters

Answer (score 3):

```
I have solved this problem. In my case, there were irrelevant dagger 
dependencies 
that the IDE did not notify me about:

   implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.35.1'
   kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.28'

After updating them, the problem disappeared and it became possible to use the 
latest version of Kotlin!

   implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.37'
   kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.37'
```

Answer (score 2):

my mistake was using `suspend` when then function returns `LiveData`.Room's coroutines integration brings ability to return suspend values but when the value itself is asnyc, there is no reason to use it.
i changed :

```
@Delete
suspend fun Delete(premiumPackageDBEntity: PremiumPackageDBEntity)

@Query("SELECT * FROM available_premium_package ")
suspend fun GetAll(): LiveData<List<PremiumPackageDBEntity>>
```

to :

```
@Delete
suspend fun Delete(premiumPackageDBEntity: PremiumPackageDBEntity)

@Query("SELECT * FROM available_premium_package ")
fun GetAll(): LiveData<List<PremiumPackageDBEntity>>
```

and the problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I forgot to add newly created entities into "entities" section of @Database declaration using Room library.

`--stacktrace --info --scan` commandline options are a great help to find the exact cause.

Answer (score 2):

I just faced a similar bug. If you're using an old dependency for Room, update and rebuild your project.

Comment: I was going to comment that until I found your comment. Indeed, I updated the room uplifted versions from 2.3.0 to 2.4.1 and it worked:

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
 kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

Answer (score 2):

For me I deleted these folders.

1. `.gradle`
2. `.idea`

> Close android studio , delete the folders and reopen the project

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

```
//implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.2"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.1"
//kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.4.2"
implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.1"
//annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.2"
```

I didn't use the ones I used. My problem was solved when I used these two. We get a kaptDebug error because there is no match with the Room. My problem was related to the implement.

Answer (score 1):

if all that tasks are not work, just run your app. You will see error log clearly.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by replacing `kapt` with `annotationProcessor` with one of the dependencies.

```
// dagger2
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.41'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.41' //this one
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.41"
```

Answer (score 0):

First change

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
```

to

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Now you have to tweak your project Gradle file and update the version of Kotlin being used which should be something like below:

`ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
        gradleVersion = '3.1.0'
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and solved it simply by following these steps

1- open File menu -> then choose Project Structure or press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+s

2- open Modules from the left

3- In Source Compatibility press the drop down menu and choose Java 8 or 1.8

4- In Target Compatibility press the drop down menu and choose Java 8 or 1.8

5- press ok then sync and rebuild your project or run it

Answer (score 0):

In my case `build.gradle`
replaced
`id` `'kotlin-android-extensions'` to
`id` 'kotlin-parcelize'
as it said on `build`

added

```
buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
```

also had a few syntax mistakes like forgetting `:` at Dao

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table_satis WHERE satisId ==:satisID")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'm using ViewBinding instead of DataBinding. And when I got the same problem I solved it with adding plugin `apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'` to gradle.

Answer (score 0):

try add to gradle.properties:

```
kapt.use.worker.api=false
kapt.incremental.apt=false
```

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of proposing a debugging experiment instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score 0):

I wrote accidentally @EntryPoint instead of @AndroidEntryPoint. Changing that error was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem. It was resolved when I changed this line:

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
```

to

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.10"
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @Yunnosch not really. it's up to him what he wants to do

Answer (score 0):

In some of the Cases if the id of the View is incorrect it always shows this error.Recheck if the id of the view is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i just updated the recently added dependencies(a newer version was available), and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using

```
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$version_glide"
```

without applying the **implementation**.

```
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$version_glide"
```

**You should check all kapt dependencies in the `build.gradle (Module)`, not just `glide`**

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to add all of these dependencies:

```
    room_version = '2.4.3'

    // Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line :

```
implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:x.x.x'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I remove the whole git project folder and clone it again and invalidate caches and restart before in IntelliJ. That was the only way for me.