# Android studio giving error 'java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)'

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dagger-hilt, kapt

I am building a hilt project and when i am building it, it is giving me this error 'Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

**This is the build.gradle file(Module)**

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.practice"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    //hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.38.1"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

**UserApplication Class**

```
 @HiltAndroidApp
class UserApplication : Application() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var userRepository:UserRepository

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        userRepository.saveUser("rahmat@gmail.com","pass123")
    }

}
```

**User Repository Class**

```
    class UserRepository @Inject constructor()  {

    fun saveUser(email:String, password:String){
        Log.e("User Repository","User saved")
    }

}
```

**'Error Screenshot
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDxWe.png**

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have enought information, try to run this steps to get more information about the error.
This topic can help with this [link to another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649694/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-org-jetbrains-kotlin-gradle-internal-kaptexec) , I'll bring some information of that topic, resumed, here.

First step is to run the command for Linux `./gradlew clean build` and for Windows `.\gradlew clean build` in Terminal of Android Studio. If it doesn't show the error try the next steps.

To get more info please go to the root item, that in your case is `Build: Failed` and select to try to get more informations

[image: your root item]
This should display some helpful error message
[image: where to search the error message]

If besides this the error doesn't show up try the next step.

In the `app/build.gradle` add this command `kapt { correctErrorTypes true }`