# Error run github action Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have the github action for app distribution in firebase and I have the following error

With com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1 ran satisfactorily, but com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2 show the error

This is my yaml file

```
name: firebase-distribution

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - qa

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Make gradlew executable
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew
      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace
      - name: Upload to Firebase Distribution
        run: ./gradlew appDistributionUploadDebug
```

Error:

```
Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Comment: Please check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850060/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appkaptdebugkotlin

Comment: thanks but no solve my problem

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Update java-version to 11 `java-version: '11'`