# Execution failed for task ':common:kaptDebugKotlin'. > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

Execution failed for task ':common:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.SharedNameTable$NameImpl)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:194)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:155)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:169)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:98)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1575)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.SharedNameTable$NameImpl)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations.annotationType(TypeAnnotations.java:231)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.separateAnnotationsKinds(TypeAnnotations.java:294)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitMethodDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1066)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(JCTree.java:778)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitClassDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1042)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$1.run(TypeAnnotations.java:127)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:152)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.enterDone(Annotate.java:129)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:512)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:471)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:982)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:229)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:192)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$invokeExtensionsOnAnalysisComplete(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:111)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:121)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:514)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:505)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:505)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:189)
    ... 24 more
```

Hello, I am getting an error in my project. How can I solve this? I can't find any information on what caused the problem. Can you help me?

My Gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        // Sdk and tools
        minSdk_version = 21
        targetSdk_version = 31
        compileSdk_version = 31
        buildTools_version = "30.0.3"

        // Gradle dependencies
        gradle_version = '4.1.3'
        kotlin_version = "1.4.32"
        googleServices_version = "4.3.4"
        crashlyticsGradle_version = "2.4.1"
        navigation_version = "2.3.3"
        hiltGradle_version = "2.33-beta"
        onesignalGradle_version= "0.12.10"
        // App dependencies
        ktx_version = "1.3.2"
        appCompat_version = "1.2.0"
        material_version = "1.3.0"
        constraintLayout_version = "2.0.4"
        fragment_version = "1.3.2"
        lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
        coroutines_version = "1.4.2"
        paging_version = "2.1.2"
        hiltViewModel_version = "1.0.0-alpha03"
        swiperefresh_version = "1.1.0"
        dataStore_version = "1.0.0-alpha06"
        browser_version = "1.3.0"
        firebaseBom_version = "26.5.0"
        playCore_version = "1.8.1"
        onesignal_version = "4.2.0"

        // 3rd App dependencies
        exoplayer_version = "2.13.1"
        glide_version = "4.12.0"
        retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
        jsoup_version = "1.13.1"
        eventbus_version = "3.2.0"
        roundedimageview_version = "2.3.0"

        //Test
        junit_version = "4.13.2"
        testExtJunit_version = "1.1.2"
        testEspresso_version = "3.3.0"
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:${gradle_version}"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:$googleServices_version"
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:$crashlyticsGradle_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hiltGradle_version"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:$onesignalGradle_version"
    }

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle properties :

```
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Comment: tale a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850060/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appkaptdebugkotlin

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work :( @mr1554

Comment: what JDK do you use? if you use 11, change it to 8 and try!

Comment: JDK 8.  @mr1554.

Answer (score 5):

You must change JDK version.

You have to upgrade from version `8` to `11`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a problem with injecting dependencies with hilt.

check the WhatEverModule class and add these annotations above the class name

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
```

There is a sample module code for database injection with hilt

```
import dagger.Module
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class DatabaseModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context): AppDatabase =
        Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "db_name")
            .allowMainThreadQueries().build()
}
```

also dont forget to add "@HiltAndroidApp" to your main Application class

```
import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class MainApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }
}
```