# error: [MissingType]: Element 'xxxxx.AppDatabase.room' references a type that is not present

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

error: [MissingType]: Element 'xxxxx.AppDatabase.room' references a type that is not present

I get the mentioned error in the title when I try to compile my code. It seems that I have a problem with Room which causes this. Kotlin kapt gives this error. How can I solve it?

Project Level Gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {


    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

        def nav_version = "2.3.5"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } // Google's Maven repository
        maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' } // HUAWEI Maven repository

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App level Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"
    flavorDimensions "default"
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ege.altaga"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true


        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("key.keystore.jks")
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'altaga'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }

    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable true
            aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


//            resValue("string", "google_device_verification_api_key", "AIzaSyDNLDM08-vLp9uszlNJH1SJW1y7oUqsA-U")
        }

        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            zipAlignEnabled true
//            resValue("string", "google_device_verification_api_key", "AIzaSyDNLDM08-vLp9uszlNJH1SJW1y7oUqsA-U")
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
//        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    }
    configurations {
        cleanedAnnotations
        compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.32"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.7'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'

    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
    def room_version =  "2.4.0-beta02"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
//    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // optional - RxJava2 support for Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
}
```

AppDatabase class

```
package com.ege.altaga.data

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.ege.altaga.data.database.player.PlayerDAO
import com.ege.altaga.data.database.player.PlayerEntity
import com.ege.altaga.data.database.square.SquareDAO
import com.ege.altaga.data.database.square.SquareEntity

@Database(entities = [(PlayerEntity::class),(SquareEntity::class)],version = 1)
abstract class AltagaDB : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract  fun playerDAO() : PlayerDAO<PlayerEntity>
    abstract  fun squareDAO() : SquareDAO<SquareEntity>

    companion object {
        @Volatile var instance: AltagaDB? = null

         fun getDatabase(context: Context): AltagaDB =
             instance ?: synchronized(this) { instance ?: buildDatabase(context.applicationContext).also { instance = it } }

         private fun buildDatabase(appContext: Context) =
             Room.databaseBuilder(appContext, AltagaDB::class.java, "AltagaDB")
                 .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                 .build()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Cleaning the project, then rebuilding helped me.

Comment: at first, it's better to define your variables in the model nullable and then increase the version of your database or remove it from the device and reinstall. it would regenerate the database.

Comment: It was solved after cleaning the project and rebuilding it.

Comment: I was getting a similar error message, but for one of the entities. I found out that the entity imported from a different library was also annotated by @Parcelize. After importing kotlin-parcelize plugin in the app module this was resolved. This only happened after migrating from kapt to ksp. I suggest checking all the transitive dependencies if ksp can really see them.

Answer (score 3):

> Run your application with  `./gradlew clean build` command to see what's exactly wrong with your code. Just paste it into the Terminal in Android Studio.

...copied word for word from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46850574/1803879). Thanks [Łukasz Kobyliński](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2600197/%c5%81ukasz-kobyli%c5%84ski), please upvote their answer.

Answer (score 2):

Many answers here, but none worked for me.

**Actual Error Faced**

> [ksp] [MissingType]: Element 'com.*****.****.cache.DataStore'
> references a type that is not present

[There is an issue with KSP room support](https://github.com/google/ksp/issues/350#issuecomment-1691842005) and which is why it is unable to read BuildConfig file that has version in it and i am using that version as below for room DB

```
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.*****.****.BuildConfig // ISSUE WITH KSP https://github.com/google/ksp/issues/350

@Database(entities = [AbcDSO::class], version= BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE, exportSchema = true)
abstract class DataStore : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun abcDAO(): AbcDAO
}
```

**Solution**

Best thing would be to remove BuildConfig import and hard code the version (or use some other way to apply versioning for room db) until this issue is resolved in version https://github.com/google/ksp/milestone/21

```
//import com.*****.****.BuildConfig --remove this app specific buildconfig reference
//hardcoded version or apply a suitable way of versioning until the ksp issue is resolved
@Database(entities = [AbcDSO::class], version= 1, exportSchema = true)
```

Comment: Yes, this was the issue in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while using room v2.4.1 with kotlin v1.5.31. The solution was to change kotlin version to 1.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

maybe u can try invalidate caches, 
`go to file -> invalidate caches.. -> then click button Invalidate and Restart` 
for me it works well with tha same error code

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part of code from your **App level Gradle** and you'll be good to go

> configurations {
> cleanedAnnotations
> compile.exclude group: 'org.jetbrains', module: 'annotations'
> }

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem After checking the code several times, I found that I forgot to add the package name in class Dao

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TpxP.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when storing Protobuf messages in Room entities (and adding conversions from/to `ByteArray`s), and none of the suggestions here helped.

I fixed this problem by adding the following to `app/build.gradle`.

```
android {
    kotlin {
        sourceSets {
            debug {
                kotlin.srcDir("build/generated/source/proto/debug/java")
            }
            release {
                kotlin.srcDir("build/generated/source/proto/release/java")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/ksp/issues/37) put me on the right track to fix this issue.

It looks like KSP (and thus Room) doesn't use the same resolution strategy as Android Studio, so even though my project built normally, once Room had references to the generated files, the project stopped building.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't sync the gradle after implementing a few dependecies. So just make sure to sync before running the project!

Answer (score -1):

I just forgot to add this line to the top of my BloodyDao Class:

```
package this.bloody.package.BloodyDao
```

adding this line solved my problem