# How can fix that failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, kotlin

When I created new Fragment,I found below error.

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Comment: This error can be caused by many reasons.
You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850060/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appkaptdebugkotlin) link.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.