# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Tags: android, kotlin

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

here are my depedencies

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cinema"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding=true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'

    //ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'

    //Recyclerview
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    // Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.5.0'

    // Gson
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"


    // Glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'




    // paging 3
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.0-beta03"


    //Rx
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.7'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'

    // Navigation Components
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.31.2-alpha"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.31.2-alpha"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}
```

Comment: this error is related to your codes implementation, many reason cause this error , i thin you need this link and probably hilt make this error see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850060/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appkaptdebugkotlin

Comment: solved this by upgrading the glide library

Comment: possible version number mismatch between Gradle and IDE Plugin, look at build.gradle and change kotlin version number to match the IDE Plugin :)