# How to implement corroutines/room correctly? Kotlin Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

have tried to implement coroutines/room in two projects and I get
the same error.
Please help me!!!

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

error: type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or a collection/array of it.
    kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super kotlin.Unit> continuation);
```

> This is my room database class:

```
@Database(entities = [Meal::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(MealTypeConvertor::class)
abstract class MealDataBase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun mealDao(): MealDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        var INSTANCE: MealDataBase? = null

        @Synchronized
        fun getInstance(context: Context): MealDataBase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    MealDataBase::class.java,
                    "meal.db"
                ).fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
            }
            return INSTANCE as MealDataBase
        }

    }
}
```

> This my model data Class with the @Entity anotation:

```
@Entity(tableName = "mealInformation")
data class Meal(
val dateModified: Any?,
@PrimaryKey
val idMeal: String,
val strArea: String?,
val strCategory: String?,
val strCreativeCommonsConfirmed: Any?,
val strDrinkAlternate: Any?,
val strImageSource: Any?,
val strIngredient1: String?
)
```

> My class is already noted with **@Entity** and my version of gradle is up to date. My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
def nav_version = "2.3.5"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

//Navigation Component
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

//intuit
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

//gif
implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.17'

//Retrofit
implementation("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0")
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

//images
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'

//videoModel mvvm
def lifecycle_version = "2.4.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1"

//room
def roomVersion = "2.4.2"
implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")

}
```

> My class is already noted with **@Entity** and my version of gradle is up to date

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you provide the piece of code that causes this error?

Comment: I vaguely recall a question along similar lines where the issue, if I recall correctly, was the mix of Java and Kotlin and the annotationProcessor/kapt both being coded.

Comment: @MikeT Thanks to you I oriented my search to solve the problem correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The previous solution was only useful for a short time, the real problem was that I had to update gradle. In the classpath I added this:

```
> buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4"
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.10'
        classpath "com.google.devtools.ksp:com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.plugin:1.7.20-Beta-1.0.6"
        ...
    }

 

    }
```

> Be sure that the ksp version match with your kotlin plugin version, you can also check the maven website here: [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.devtools.ksp/com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.plugin)

Then in the build.gradle add the ksp plugin, add the new ksp compileOption and change the kap annotatons to ksp:

```
    plugins {
    ...
    ...
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp'
    }
    android{
    ...
    ksp {
        arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas".toString())
    }
    ...
    
}
dependencies {
    ...
    //room
    def roomVersion = "2.4.3"

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion"
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
    ...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> [**READ THE NEW ANSWER**] After trying a lot of things I finally found the error, which was very
> stupid. The problem was that I repeated twice the implementation of
> the room-compiler dependency.
>
> I deleted the kapt dependency. Anyway this link helped me to identify the problem [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850060/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appkaptdebugkotlin.)