# Kotlin kapt unable to see support annotations

Tags: java, android, gradle, annotations, kotlin

I added kotlin to an exhausting Java project. Everything compiled and works until adding kapt for annotation processing. Now, I am getting
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing`

and a bunch of the warnings dispalyed are 

`e:   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
e:    ^
e:   symbol:   class Retention
e:   location: class RegistryDef`

and

`e:   @StringDef({ASCENDING_ORDER, DESCENDING_ORDER, SortOrder.UNKNOWN})
e:    ^
e:   symbol:   class StringDef
e:   location: class RegistryDef`

I added the support annotations explicitly to the project just to ensure they are included and use Gradle to force all versions to the latest.

Has anyone experienced this and how did you solve it?

Comment: It may helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45016580/2949612