# Getting a GradleException: Compilation error

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

I get a `Gradle Exception: Compilation error` during app building

I've tried rebuilding, cleaning, syncing to no avail

> org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more
>   details at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:14)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:122)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:146)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:141)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runJvmCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:81)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:449)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompilerAsync$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:359)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.executeImpl(Tasks.kt:316)
>   at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:288)
>   at java.util.Optional.map at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I dont know what the error log above means. What could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Post some more information about your issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on `Gradle` (on the right side bar) then under `:app` choose `assembleDebug` (or `assembleYourFlavor` if you use flavors). Error will show up in Run tab. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51022296