# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, debugging

I tried running the default flutter app from **flutter create** on my android device but it throws me an error. Can someone help?

> Launching lib\main.dart on SM G610F in debug mode... Running Gradle
>   task 'assembleDebug'...
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'. . . .
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 14s Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug
>   failed with exit code 1

This is my flutter doctor:

> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows
>   [Version 10.0.10586], locale en-US)
>       • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at E:\flutter\flutter
>       • Framework revision 27321ebbad (6 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
>       • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
>       • Dart version 2.7.0
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 29.0.2)
>       • Android SDK at C:\Users\208046\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
>       • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
>       • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
>       • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
>       • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
>       • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
>       • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
>       • Dart plugin version 191.8593
>       • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
>
> [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.41.1)
>       • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
>       • Flutter extension version 3.7.1
>
> [√] Connected device (1 available)
>       • SM G610F • 33005566b2b5c3df • android-arm • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)
>
> • No issues found!

edit: for my complete logs you can see here:

[Flutter github issues](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49419)

Comment: As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848845/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugkotlin-compilation-error), this could be an issue with the android/kotlin build. I assume you successfully created a flutter project. In that case did you try to do a `flutter clean`. Also please mention the steps you already followed, that could help.

Comment: All I did was create a new flutter project from VS Code and run on my device. That's it. This is very frustrating because I created a web flutter project and I can run it just fine.

Comment: Please don't be frustrated. :-) Based on the logs in your github post it looks like the build process is trying to download some `jar` files which are not available in server. Good that you posted the same in Github. Just a hunch, could you try to run on a simulator instead of a device.

Comment: I just recreated the project on my coworker pc and it ran fine on android device

Comment: I had the same problem but for release: `Execution failed for task ':fluttertoast:compileReleaseKotlin'.` And `flutter clean` took care of it!  (When will I learn to just try that for all problems?! ‍♀️)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it. It was because of my network blocked non secured http download request. I changed my network and the gradle build completed itself.

Answer (score 112):

Go to your `build.gradle` file in the root of your Android directory and upgrade your `Kotlin_version` to the latest. As of the time of typing this, the latest is 1.5.10, so it should look like this:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
```

You can find the latest Kotlin version [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details).

Comment: Thank you! It fixed my problem when adding the package audioplayers: ^0.19.0   I started on the flutter code using 'Flutter create'  2 days ago and this created a build.gradle file with  'ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'

Comment: Is there a place explaning the update process of such things? For example my dependencies classpath is also requesting some sort of update

Comment: Which exact dependencies is requesting an update?

Comment: It's works with me, thanks

Comment: sometimes you may get **':app:mergeDexDebug'** error after this fix. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/60311131/10505343 after that

Comment: this works perfectly thank you. I found the build.gradle under the project->android->build.gradle

Comment: thanks worked for me. By the way don't forget after upgrade kotlin version.

Comment: FYI, to find the **latest Kotiln's version**, you can get i from [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details)

Answer (score 55):

Solved the problem by deleting `android/.gradle` and then run the app in debug mode

Comment: where can i find in Mac?

Comment: @Zionnite does not matter which OS you are using. `flutter_project_root/android/.gradle`

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? Someone deserves the credit!

Comment: what is inside that folder ?

Comment: Solved by "flutter clean" then "flutter pub get"

Answer (score 34):

A possible fix can be upgrading the project/android/build.gradle
Steps to fix,

1. flutter clean
2. Delete android/.gradle
3. Go to android/build.gradle, upgrade `ext.kotlin_version` to latest. In my case(1.3.0 -> 1.5.10), `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'`

After doing this as well, I was getting `A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'kotlin-android']
> The current Gradle version 5.6.2 is not compatible with the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Please use Gradle 6.1 or newer, or the previous version of the Kotlin plugin.`

To fix this,

1. Go to `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`
2. Update the distributionUrl to the latest version.In my case((5.6.2 -> 6.1.1) it is,
   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip`

Answer (score 12):

It was fixed after I upgraded my build.gradle file `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'`

First of all run

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Go to `andriod/build.gradle`
then upgrade `ext.kotlin_version`

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For me, I found that when building that 2 different MainActivity.kt files were in `andriod/app/src/main/kotlin`. One had a default MainActivity.kt file with the package name that was originally generated for my project. Something like 'example.project_name' . The other one had what I changed my project name into. I went ahead and deleted the folder with the MainActivity.kt containing the import starting with 'example.project_name' and that resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

in android folder of your project run in terminal

```
gradlew clean
```

Then build. This worked for me.

Comment: Showing gradew is not recognizable? why?

Comment: @ProCo which  OS are you using? if it is linux, cd into your project's android/ and then try doing ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 4):

It was fixed after I upgraded my Flutter by running `flutter upgrade`

Answer (score 4):

I Solved it by upgrading kotlin version in root `build.gradle` file:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
```

Answer (score 4):

First of make sure that you have latest version of flutter.
For confirmation,
please run ***flutter upgrade*** in command prompt / terminal:

```
flutter upgrade
```

Then visit the site [Click Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions)
and copy the new latest version of kotlin.
For now: in March 02, 2022 current kotlin version is ***1.6.10***

Then after it:

```
-> Go to android/build.gradle
-> change to ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

[Click here to view Screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulPFC.png)

Comment: its not always the case to upgrade the flutter. in case of the old projects upgrading versions without knowing the issue can make so much problem

Answer (score 4):

I Update Flutter from 2.10.4 to Flutter 3.0.0  and I found All My Project Has Same Error

ensure that your ext.kotlin_version is '1.6.10'

> `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'`

and run in terminal

> `flutter pub cache repair`

and show that your libraries in `pubspec.yamel` take last version
and run in terminal

> 1 - `flutter clean`
>
> 2 - `flutter pub get`

in android studio open File --> invalidate cashes..

this worked for me !!

if this not work for you
you may be need to

> `Delete android/.gradle`

thank you .

Comment: flutter pub cache repair |
 Saved my day

Answer (score 3):

I got the problem after migrating to null-safety. I fixed it by updating the kotlin version in the file android\build.gradle

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

Then run 'flutter clean' and the app worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have been facing this issue for couple of hours. At the end right now my issue solved by executing following steps -

```
- change Settings -> Build, Execution, Development -> Compiler -> Kotlin Compiler -> Kotlin to JVM -> check Enable incremental comilation -> Target JVM version 1.6 to 1.8

- add to build.gradle under repositories in both buildscript and allprojects section

maven {
        url 'http://download.flutter.io'
    }

-and lastly run on command line 'flutter pub cache repair'
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I encountred the same problem and tried all the solutions proposed here in this post ... and still not working.

but only after upgrading the packages in pubspec.yaml with:

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

it worked !!

Answer (score 2):

> Just increase the ext.kotlin.version from whatever version you have, to '1.4.32' or whatever the latest version is available
> [kotline version](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html)

Answer (score 2):

Update to the latest version in my case it is 1.6.10 or create dummy project and check android/build.gradle and update.

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, upgrade to Flutter 3.7.6 solved my problem, just run on your terminal

```
flutter upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

In our case, the package [flutter_appcenter_bundle](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appcenter_bundle) caused this issue.

To fix it, you need to run `flutter precache`.

This needs to be done only once and it will be effective as long as the Flutter version remains unchanged and the precached artifacts are not deleted (e.g. by deleting the Flutter root folder).

Also, the environment variable `FLUTTER_ROOT` needs to be set to the Flutter root folder. On Windows it's usually `C:\src\flutter`.

If you use AndroidStudio, you can do that in *Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter*.

If you don't use AndroidStudio, you need to set `FLUTTER_ROOT` manually.

Comment: This solved my problem (been hunting for the solution for multiple days now). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

when I ran flutter upgrade in the command line prompt it was fixed and ran my app .. try it

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
[Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWUYA.png)

solution:
Changed the company domain with only one dot.
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8OqF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was using JRE for Java. I just install the AdoptOpenJDK 11 and it works

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to set the `JavaVersion` according to the Kotlin version.

So to fix this error:

> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.7) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 17)

I had to set this values in the file `build.gradle`:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For me, my package name imported twice automatically in MainActivity file under app>main>kotlin directory. I just delete duplicates and it works fine now!

Answer (score -1):

Please verify your existing Kotlin version. If you're working with Android Studio, you can do this by navigating to **Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates**. Once you've identified the current version, proceed to the android/build.gradle file and update the `ext.kotlin_version` to match that version.

Answer (score -3):

For me, I had some syntax error in [image]android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/<pakckage_name>/app/MainActivity.kt

Answer (score -3):

Run "flutter clean" and get dependencies again