# google_maps_flutter Not compatible with flutter_facebook_login

Tags: flutter

I'm having difficulties to implement 'flutter_facebook_login package' in project that uses 'google_maps_flutter'.

The project works fine when I delete the 'flutter_facebook_login' package, but when I try to use this package, I get an error and the project wasn't build.

```
'Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 70285 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.'
```

When I tried to fix this issue with setting in my **Build.gradle 'multiDexEnabled true'*. The Maps stopped to work.

I tried this: [Execution-failed-for-task-appmergedexdebug-firestore-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60310873/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedexdebug-firestore-flutter)
and this: [Multidex-issue-with-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886597/multidex-issue-with-flutter)

```
//Build.gradle implemented MULTIDEXENABLE = TRUE
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.unMatch"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

**Error Log**

```
D8: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 70285 > 65536)
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:444)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:56)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:215)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:210)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:55)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 70285 > 65536)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:21)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:7)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile.a(:33)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile$h.a(:5)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.a(:13)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.write(:35)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:44)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:23)
        ... 36 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:55)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
        ... 34 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 70285 > 65536)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:21)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:7)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile.a(:33)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.VirtualFile$h.a(:5)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.a(:13)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationWriter.write(:35)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:44)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:23)
        ... 36 more


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
     Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

**UPDATE**
I tried:
I got this error when I try to getLocation

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method requestPermissions on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods
```

Change minSdkVersion 16 to 21.

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.unMatch"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

I tried to change LocationPermission plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For errors like this looking deep into Github Issues can be more useful. From what I've seen, setting the `minSdkVersion` to `21` has solved the issue for people without setting `multiDexEnabled true`. Others required both changes to be done. Either way, your `minSdkVersion` is too low.

[Issue Reference](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20747#issuecomment-456383769)

Comment: Not work :c 
I've tried too: change to other LocationPermission Plugin. Verify AndroidX compatible. Tried override MainActivity.kt OnCreate. None worked.

Comment: I got this error when I try to getLocation 
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method requestPermissions on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods

Comment: Please share your `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: And share the following 2 files: `/android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml` & `/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: I noticed that I removed the implementations of `strings.xml` and facebook values in `AndroidManifest.xml` in the course of attempts to resolve the error. After I read your comment, I re-implemented and now it worked.. I'm a dumb haha. So, `minSdkVersion` to `21` is the answer. Very Thank you for your attention. You helped me a lot <3