# Flutter App: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, android-emulator

I get this error when I try to execute my app on a phone through Android Studio. I tried running `flutter clean` but it didn't work

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
 > A failure occurred while executing 
   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
 > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while 
 merging dex archives: 
 The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
 Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

 * Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info 
or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
 insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 2m 44s
 [!] The shrinker may have failed to optimize the Java bytecode.
  To disable the shrinker, pass the `--no-shrink` flag to this command.
  To learn more, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code
 Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Does someone know how to help me?

Comment: I think its related to multidex. I think you can find solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60311131/10256415)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go fix these errors is to run the following commands:

1. `flutter clean`
2. `flutter build appbundle --no-sound-null-safety`

If the issue persists try running `-info` after the commands then read the logs, it will give you leads to find out the problem.