# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

> Failed to transform common-27.0.1.jar (com.android.tools:common:27.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.

```
  > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\MyPc\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools\common\27.0.1\62d59d2a0ee7d0cd7bbeba97ddce45f7898ec6c6\common-27.0.1.jar.

     > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\MyPc\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools\common\27.0.1\62d59d2a0ee7d0cd7bbeba97ddce45f7898ec6c6\common-27.0.1.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
```

> Failed to transform bundletool-0.13.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.13.2) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.

```
  > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\MyPc\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.build\bundletool\0.13.2\bb629ece022e5aa20cff66517e728c89f9667721\bundletool-0.13.2.jar.

     > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\MyPc\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.tools.build\bundletool\0.13.2\bb629ece022e5aa20cff66517e728c89f9667721\bundletool-0.13.2.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries
```

using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

Comment: Did you try with `flutter clean` and rebuild again, if it doesn't work, maybe you need to change Kotlin version on  android directory.

Comment: [Please try this out, this may work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67817286/16766799)

Comment: Yes i tried several times. but the same issue occurs . Also change the Kotline version ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.15'

Comment: @WasiqHussain how did you fix this?