# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. I got this error in a flutter a project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59893018/flutter-execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugkotlin)

Comment: have you tried by upgrading kotlin version?