# Error while using flutter background_location package

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I just imported the package [background_location](https://pub.dev/packages/background_location), and didn't use it. Even though I get this error

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':background_location:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Tried changing kotlin version, changed minSdkVersion but no change.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can do:

1. run flutter clean and flutter pub get and then try again.
2. go to your android/app/build.gradle and upgrade the Kotlin version. Latest right now is 1.6.0 i.e. `ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'`
3. Go to android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and upgrade distributionURL to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip`

This is where I got these solutions from, [Flutter: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59893018/flutter-execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugkotlin).

Update: Change your dependency in your pubspec.yaml to:

```
background_location: 
    git:
      url: https://github.com/hilalbaig/background_location.git
      ref: master
```

Here is the reference: https://github.com/Almoullim/background_location/issues/150#issuecomment-1132144094

Comment: already tried all of these

Comment: what version are you using of background_location?

Comment: background_location: ^0.8.1 .  latest

Comment: I have updated my solution, please check if it solves.