# in_app_update:compileDebugKotlin error in Flutter build when debugging

Tags: flutter, kotlin, gradle

I had this issue when I try to setup my project on my new pc.
[image]

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':in_app_update:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction

I tried to find the solution here and some says its because of the kotlin version
[image]

I need some pointers out here, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at the solutions in this link?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59893018/flutter-execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugkotlin

Comment: I tried the steps where I have to upgrade the kotlin version

Comment: This problem can sometimes be related to gradlew. I recommend that you check it out.

Comment: I checked it out, and still same problem, i upgraded the kotlin version too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more context is hard to say, but when compilation fails the errors are usually listed somewhere else (before the failure). Read the whole output of Gradle and look for lines starting with `e:`.

---

Looking at your first image which says:

> > Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin
> 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' task (current target is 1.7) and 'compileDebugKotlin' task (current target is 1.8) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

Depending on your Kotlin version and `gradle.properties` contents the JVM incompatibility might be a warning or an error. Since it doesn't say "it will become an error", suggests that the flag is on `error`.

This is the part I'm missing:

> By default will become an error since Gradle 8.0+! Read more: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/target-validation
> Consider using JVM toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain

So you have a few options. Set up your `PATH` / `JAVA_HOME` to point to Java 7 installation, I think you have Java 8 now, but the project expects 7 (or the other way around). Without seeing `targetCompatibility` / `jvmTarget` DSL, it's hard to tell.

Anyway, just recently we reported a similar issue to Kotlin and they provided a very clean solution: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-24311/#focus=Comments-27-6798448.0-0

`build.gradle` (for each module):

```kotlin
kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(7)
}
```

This is what the documentation also suggests.

---

If you can't make it work by juggling Java versions, you can disable the warning and maybe that will make it work:

`gradle.properties`:

```
kotlin.jvm.target.validation.mode=ignore
```

This is [documented here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle-configure-project.html#check-for-jvm-target-compatibility-of-related-compile-tasks). Please understand what you're turning off and that it'll break things now or in the future if you do.