# flutter webrtc give an error with github jetpack, couldn't run the applicatioin

Tags: flutter, flutter-webrtc

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_webrtc:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_webrtc:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find android-104.5112.03.jar (com.github.webrtc-sdk:android:104.5112.03).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jitpack.io/com/github/webrtc-sdk/android/104.5112.03/android-104.5112.03.jar
```

Comment: This is may be problem in your kotlin version. update the your kotlin version  inside build.gradle file or follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59893018/flutter-execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugkotlin

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
com.github.webrtc-sdk from app/build.gradle
```

and add this

```
 implementation 'com.github.webrtc-sdk:android:104.5112.07'
```