# Android Studio : Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I tried to begin with flutter. But the very basic app (created by the flutter team itself) shows the following error.

```
"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'. > Compilation error. See log for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848845/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugkotlin-compilation-error)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete `.gradle` folder in `android` folder, and run the app again.