# @appdynamics/react-native-agent throws Task :appdynamics_react-native-agent:compileDebugKotlin FAILED in android react native

Tags: android, react-native, npm, appdynamics, app-dynamics-query-language

I am trying to integrate app dynamics in my react native project. we have upgraded react native version in our project from 0.66.4 to 0.70.0

App dynamics is working fine in android with previous version of react but does not works with upgraded version and throws error as below while running the application in android studio.

**Task :appdynamics_react-native-agent:compileDebugKotlin FAILED**

@appdynamics/react-native-agent version is 22.5.0
react native version: 0.70.0
Android gradle plugin version: 7.2.1
Gradle version: 7.5.1

Please help me on this issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps the solutions here may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848845/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugkotlin-compilation-error